# ListView.Items.Add adding a ListViewItem to wrong ListView

Tags: c#, listview, listviewitem

I have two ListView objects in my code, MovieList and UserFriendList. I have a method that looks like this

```
public void passFriends(ListViewItem[] friends)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem tempItem in friends)
        {
            ListViewItem temp = new ListViewItem();
            temp = (ListViewItem)tempItem.Clone();
            UserFriendList.Items.Add(temp);
        }
    }
```

The method is designed to pass an array of ListViewItems from one form to another, and then add each listview item to the UserFriendList. However, when I actually perform the action, the ListViewItem (a User) is added to my MovieList instead of my UserFriendsList

Does anybody know why this could be happening?

Comment: where is the MovieList here?

Comment: MovieList isn't part of this method which is why its so baffling. However the code to initialize MovieList and add Columns to it is found in the constructor for the form

Comment: what is the value you are getting in the temp variable? what is the type/

Comment: The only way the temp items you are seemingly added to UserFriendList being displayed in MovieList is if UserFriendList is a reference to MovieList.  That is, if the code shown is the actual code being executed.  One thing you can try is to do a clean and recompile first.  Then look and see that you are not assigning MovieList to UserFriendList.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but why are you creating a new instance of temp, then assigning a different object to temp in the next line? Why not do: `ListViewItem temp = (ListViewItem)tempItem.Clone();` ?

Comment: I originally had that code implemented but tried this out to see if it affected the result. I intend on changing it back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question can be closed. I found the issue with my problem. A section of legacy code that was used to demonstrate list switching wasn't removed and it was changing the listview of UserFriendList